# Redshift sum and round function discrepancy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Applied sum and round function some of the values not generated properly in Redshift.

```
round((field1+field2),1)
```

[image]

Comment: I presume you are saying that all the highlighted rows should have the same value since they are rounding `73.45`? Is it possible that `a` and `b` actually have more digits, but your SQL client is not showing them? Try `select a::text, b::text from ...` to see the raw values in those fields.

Comment: Yes, you are right,One more help Can we convert 73.43 to 73.5?

Comment: What rule would you be applying for this conversion? Is it "go to the closest .5"? Maybe `ROUND(value*2,0)/2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When strange results come from an SQL query, it is possible that your SQL client is rounding the values displayed on-screen.

To check this, **convert numbers to text to show their real value in the database**, preventing them from being modified by your SQL client.

For example:

```
SELECT a, a::TEXT, b, b::TEXT
```